# "Revert" command in AppleScript on OS X Lion

Tags: applescript, osx-lion

I'm in the middle of putting together a script that manipulates an OmniGraffle document and saves the result of each progressive manipulation as a PNG. That's all working fine, but at the end of process, I want to close the file *without* saving the changes.

Naturally, I reached for the "revert" command. Except that "revert" doesn't appear to *be* a command on Lion. I tried "close saving no," but since it was autosaving as each manipulation was made, that didn't work.

Of course, I can simply leave the document open and manually revert it. Nevertheless....

Am I missing something? Is there truly no way to programmatically roll back changes made to a file using AppleScript on Lion?

Update: it appears to be worse than I expected — on a volume without permanent version storage, at least — after many manipulations with AppleScript, "Revert Document…" was no longer even available in the File menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only think of a workaround: since you're not interested in keeping those intermediate versions anyway, you could:

- make a backup copy of the file prior to opening it in OmniGraffle
- do your changes + PNG exports
- close w/o saving
- overwrite the file with the backup copy (and delete the backup)

Comment: Since the Versions is a fairly recent feature of Mac OS X, Apple is likely to include commands such as "revert" in future versions of AppleScript.

Comment: But didn't "revert" exist as a command prior to Lion? My google searching, at least, seemed to suggest that it was there. Perhaps that was just for certain applications that "rolled their own"?

Comment: it must have been a (scriptable) functionality of single applications